How to handle Staging Ground questions that get published with unaddressed issues
I encountered this question, which has major issues and has subsequently been closed. I offered some feedback and warned the new user that their question would be closed to try and soften the blow somewhat.
Later that day, I went to the Staging Ground and found the same question had previously been sent to the SG. None of the major issues raised were addressed and yet it still got published.
Now there is a new user who may be feeling disheartened from a (justifiably) closed question. As far as I am aware, this is precisely the type of scenario that the SG is designed to avoid. I reserve judgment on why it got published, but given the discussion regarding SG onboarding in this post, is there a mechanism to guide reviewers who publish questions that are not ready to go live?
I considered raising a custom flag but thought I would check here first to avoid unnecessary work for the mods. Perhaps a friendly comment to the user who published the question explaining the issue would be more appropriate, but to me publishing the question appears to be an egregious action.

I can't see the post in SG but if it was never reviewed, it will be automatically posted by the system after some amount of time - see point 3 in the FAQ under the asking section. "Your post will leave the Staging Ground when one of the following happens: 3. Your post does not receive timely feedback, in which case your post will be automatically posted."

@Catija - in the SG post itself, it says that it was published by the user who answered it in the main SO site. No indication as far as I can tell that it was auto-published. Does the system give an indication if it does get auto-published?

Ah, OK. Sorry. I misunderstood that it was actually published by someone... I don't know whether review suspensions exist for SG but this seems like the sort of situation that benefits from having ways to draw attention to/identify users who regularly approve questions that later get closed to determine whether they're reviewing questions appropriately. Finding the right permissions for new features can be challenging - it's completely possible that not everyone reviewing actually knows how to determine whether a question is a good fit for the site.

The close reason selected does not seem to fit at all. How is that requesting off-site resources?

Also, please don't tell people things like "SO is primarily for debugging existing coding issues".  We should be discouraging debugging questions, as they're often the least useful to future users.  Many of the most useful questions are not about debugging.

Whoa, looking at those SG comments most of them are absolutely useless. Barely actionable, just generic, canned shotgun comments. The closure is equally bad feedback. Seriously, the problem here isn’t that comments weren’t addressed…

@MisterMiyagi One issue is that the templates aren't written in a way that really encourages using them as templates: that is, they don't afford filling in details or clarifying how the template applies in context.

Regarding raising a custom flag: If you see a user repeatedly approving bad-quality posts, that's an option IMO. Alternatively, you can also try to contact the reviewer via chat or similar.

concerning the specific example, I would have published this. honestly, as a non R-SME, I might even have published rev 1. also, a custom flag is probably overkill unless you're noticing a pattern of a specific reviewer publishing things that clearly need more work.

Regarding this question
When OP doesn't ask for a tool or library etc., and it seems reasonable to expect a priori (i.e., for someone who doesn't already know the answer) that a tool wouldn't be required (e.g., because it should be a short piece of code or something provided by the standard library), the "seeking tools" close reason is generally not applicable. Carefully check the question for other closure reasons (especially "needs more focus"), and leave it open if it doesn't qualify to be closed. Sometimes a slight bit of interpretation is needed, and the close reasons aren't necessarily factored optimally, but overall they are a very accurate guide to what makes a useful question that merits an answer and which would benefit the site.
Regarding bad questions generally
If you see something that should be closed, vote to close it. If you see something that should be downvoted, downvote it. It's a shame if the SG failed to filter something - but in the long run, the SG will successfully filter a lot. It's not your fault if you see something get through that shouldn't have - when you take normal curation actions, you're doing your self-assigned duty as a curator, and helping improve the site. The fault (assuming a consensus that your judgment is correct) lies with the person who approved the question in SG.
Improving the system
It'd be kinda nice if SG questions couldn't be unilaterally approved by anyone (which seems to be how it currently works). But so far, we don't have the resources to make it feasible any other way. There's still discourse about whether we can accept questions sitting around for however long and simply not getting reviewed by anyone. (Although to my understanding, the system is supposed to scale the fraction of questions sent to SG to try and avoid this.)
More importantly, I agree that the system should have something in place to discourage users from approving SG questions that shouldn't be approved. Ideally, it would reward all correct SG actions (as based on consensus), and penalize (in the broadest sense) all incorrect SG actions (but especially approving something that shouldn't be, or voting as off topic when the question meets standards, or hammering as a clearly wrong duplicate).
These might be hard to distinguish overall, but I think we can pick the low hanging fruit to start - and we don't need audits to make this work. All we need is to track how questions fare after being published, and in some way associate those scores with the approving users. A simple reputation share is unlikely to be good enough, but a system similar to the Q-ban algorithm could be used to suspend users from SG reviews if they approve too many questions that go on to be downvoted and/or closed. But this is completely off the top of my head, so it's not ready for a feature-request yet.
And, yes, there should also be onboarding. But that's just part of a general onboarding problem. If you have users who have been here for 10 years and can't figure out their way around the SG or accurately mark issues with questions - that's almost certainly not because the SG interface needs work (although it certainly could be improved) - it's because those users have been here for 10 years and never been forced to understand our standards for questions.

"track how questions fare" I think it's at least worth notifying the person approving the publication somehow about the fate of the question. Perhaps something like a banner on the next visit to SG: "STOP! The last question you approved was nuked from orbit. Please review the purpose of SG somewhere before participating again".

@PasserBy Why not notify the person(s) doing the nuking? "STOP! This question was approved in SG. Are you sure this question should be closed?"

@MisterMiyagi Whether a question should be nuked shouldn't depend on if it came from SG. Coming from SG doesn't make a question automatically good, evidently.

@MisterMiyagi Among other reasons, because the person(s) doing the nuking presumably each have 3k rep and possibly a gold tag badge, whereas the SG approver has 500 rep and possibly two successful questions (until the latter requirement is removed).

@PasserBy No, what does make a question automatically worthy to be nuked, then? Closure consensus?Because I am looking at the question in question that has been nuked, kicked while it was down, and still had to take names after standing back up - and it is not the SG reviewer who I would wag my finger at.

@KarlKnechtel Out of all the qualifications you just mentioned, having two successful questions seems like the best. By a long shot.

"the system should have something in place to discourage users from approving SG questions that shouldn't be approved" - I agree and there were things like that discussed during the beta (like that which matches your suggestions but would be too risky for now I guess).

@MisterMiyagi Notifying the reviewers in the way you are suggesting makes it seem like it's always their fault. In most cases, it's not the reviewers fault if a question is badly received (this would be the case with things like spam), see the reviewer guidelines. I'd say the issue is reviewers repeated approving bad questions (e.g. lacking details).

The two questions requirement is actually removed since a few (2-3) days now. cc @MisterMiyagi

@AbdulAzizBarkat I'm well aware of that.

@dan1st I haven’t suggested notifying SG reviewers, so I have literally no idea what you’re talking about.

@MisterMiyagi My fault, I misread your first comment. Anyways, telling people to reconsider closing because a question was approved is probably not a good idea. It's perfectly normal that questions getting published still lack details which only subject matter experts would know how about asking.

@dan1st Then why scold SG reviewers for approving questions, if closure is perfectly normal? I can see addressing both due to the lack of consensus, but singling out one side does not seem justified. It’s sadly perfectly normal that people get creative with close reasons.

I don't think reviewers should be told they've made a mistake just because one question they approved was published (though I think that should be done if that happens "too often"). Telling people closing approved SG questions on the main site that's wrong/they should care doesn't make sense IMO because in most cases, these posts should be closed. If a post is approved, it doesn't mean it's a good post and it is often legitimate for a reviewer to publish a post and also legitimate for people on the main site to close that same post.
